# How to access a "interval day to second" object within a row

Tags: python, pyspark

How can I access such an object in pyspark, see object values on right column, which was calculated as a difference of two timestamps columns?

this is the schema ouptut:

```
root
 |-- DeviceId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Timestamp_Device_Local: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- Timestamp_Product: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- LastCleaning: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- TimeSinceLastCleaning: long (nullable = true)
 |-- TimeSinceLastCleaningObj: interval day to second (nullable = true)
```

[image]

I know that there is a workaround to use unix-timestamps to calcualte the time delta, but I was still wondering how I can achieve the extraction from this object.

Comment: extraction of seconds from the object?

Comment: exactly, within the objects of column TimeSinceLastCleaningObj